# My java program freezes when other window is active

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I have developed a java program that runs fine in Mac OS X (10.6.7).
But if I click on another window such as Finder or another application, my program freezes, or the graphics are not updated anymore. If I click on my program again the graphics are updated again and runs well.

Does anyone know what that can be?

I coded it with the LWJGL and slick libraries.

Thanks!

Comment: *"Does anyone know what that can be?"*  The code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [here](http://slick.javaunlimited.net/viewtopic.php?t=2252):

> By default slick will not render anything if it does not have focus,
>   so good practice for applets is to set
>
> `container.setAlwaysRender(true);`
>
> so that it always renders even when it doesn't have focus.

This seems to refer to [GameContainer.setAlwaysRender](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/GameContainer.html#setAlwaysRender%28boolean%29). Although the forum post talks about applet, both AppGameContainer (standalone-application) and AppletGameContainer.Container extend from it.